# Help understanding set-builder notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm self-studying set theory by reading Charles Pinter's "A Book of Set Theory" in which he introduces Von Neumann Set Theory.

In the book, he introduces the following notation thanks to the Axiom of Class Construction

$C=\{x: P(x)\}$

as "$C$ is the class of all the elements $x$ which satisfy $P(x)$"

This makes sense to me, but then he starts using the following notation later in the book without a formal explanation. For example, here's how he defines "inverse image" for a function $f: A \rightarrow B$ and $C \subseteq A$

$\breve{f}(D)=\{x \in A: f(x) \in D\}$

How do I interpret this notation, namely $x \in A$? Is this just equivalent to

$\breve{f}(D)=\{x : x \in A \land f(x) \in D\}$

If so, what does it mean to evaluate $f(x)$ for $x \notin A$ given that there has been no short-circuit evaluation of $\land$ introduced in the book.

Thanks for taking the time to read this! I hope this makes sense.

Comment: How did they define $f(x)\in D$? It might not need the "act of evaluating". For example $\exists y\in D:\ (x,y)\in f$, which will be false for all $x$ not in the domain of $f$.

Comment: Yes, you are correct but I don't understand why you need the extra notation. The inverse of a set $D$ is simply the set of elements in the domain that get mapped to that $D$.

Comment: The condition that x∈A is redundant, and only there for clarity to emphasize to the reader that x is an element of A, not an arbitrary element of the universe. It also makes it self evident that the inverse image is a subset of the Domain of f. The condition that f(x) ∈ D, gives us that x∈A, because A is the domain for the function f. Rather than think of f(x) as a function evaluated at a point, think of it as the second coordinate in an ordered pair; so  if f(x) = y, then (x,f(x)) = (x,y). From that perspective, it doesn't even make sense to ask about evaluating f(x) at some x not in A.